# Facing difficulty to chose right plotting graph in python for large categories

Tags: python, matplotlib, plotly, visualization

I have data frame with 3 columns. Language, Total Value and Percentage . I am not sure which plotting to use in python for better visualization.

Below is the data:

```
import pandas as pd

data={'Language':['Haitian,Creole','Dutch','French','English','Xhosa','Afrikaans','Lati','Galicia','Quechua','Danish','Western,Frisia','Xhosa,French','French,Xhosa','Spanish','Norwegian,Nynorsk','Norwegia','Germa','Indonesia','Interlingua','Romania','French,English','Interlingue','Czech','Scots','Uzbek','Manx','Luxembourgish','Malagasy','Irish','Slovak','Inupiaq','Morisye','English,French','Finnish','Dutch,Afrikaans','Afar','Corsica','Portuguese','Dutch,English','Sundanese','Kinyarwanda','Malay','VolapÃ¼k','Afrikaans,Dutch','Wolof','Basque','Estonia','Italia','Lithuania','Scottish,Gaelic','Hungaria','Breto','Kalaallisut','Welsh','Zhuang','Lingala','Occita','Maori','Khasi','Maltese','Seselwa,Creole,French','Vietnamese','Tagalog','Fijia','zzp','Romansh','Bislama','Polish','Swedish','Xhosa,English','English,Dutch','Catala','Hmong','Turkme','Somali','Nyanja','Turkish','Oromo','Ganda','Tswana','Javanese','Southern,Sotho','Samoa','Guarani','Aymara','Naur','Waray','Icelandic','Rundi','Latvia','Shona','Klingo','Tonga','Cebuano','Igbo','Aka','French,Dutch','Hawaiia','Esperanto','Albania','Yoruba','Swahili','Breton,French','Dutch,Danish','Serbia'],'Total_Value':['180455','86394','40609','18355','17882','2508','483','362','259','258','247','209','172','162','156','139','130','71','70','64','45','39','38','33','33','30','29','27','26','24','22','21','20','17','16','14','14','13','13','13','12','11','11','10','9','9','9','8','8','8','7','7','6','6','6','6','6','6','6','5','5','5','5','5','4','4','4','4','4','4','3','3','3','3','3','3','2','2','2','2','2','2','2','2','2','2','2','2','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1'],'Percentage':['0.515799403','0.246942305','0.116073802','0.052464592','0.051112604','0.007168684','0.001380572','0.001034714','0.000740307','0.000737448','0.000706007','0.00059739','0.000491632','0.000463049','0.000445899','0.000397307','0.000371583','0.000202941','0.000200083','0.000182933','0.000128625','0.000111475','0.000108616','0.0000943','0.0000943','0.0000857','0.0000829','0.0000772','0.0000743','0.0000686','0.0000629','0.00006','0.0000572','0.0000486','0.0000457','0.00004','0.00004','0.0000372','0.0000372','0.0000372','0.0000343','0.0000314','0.0000314','0.0000286','0.0000257','0.0000257','0.0000257','0.0000229','0.0000229','0.0000229','0.00002','0.00002','0.0000171','0.0000171','0.0000171','0.0000171','0.0000171','0.0000171','0.0000171','0.0000143','0.0000143','0.0000143','0.0000143','0.0000143','0.0000114','0.0000114','0.0000114','0.0000114','0.0000114','0.0000114','0.00000857','0.00000857','0.00000857','0.00000857','0.00000857','0.00000857','0.00000572','0.00000572','0.00000572','0.00000572','0.00000572','0.00000572','0.00000572','0.00000572','0.00000572','0.00000572','0.00000572','0.00000572','0.00000286','0.00000286','0.00000286','0.00000286','0.00000286','0.00000286','0.00000286','0.00000286','0.00000286','0.00000286','0.00000286','0.00000286','0.00000286','0.00000286','0.00000286','0.00000286','0.00000286']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I don't know which is the best way to visualize this three attributes using matplotlib,seaborn,plotly

Language column has 106 categories and it has equivalent total value and percentage column

Request help to provide good interpretable visualization graph

**Tried with below code I could see only 52 languages in x axis**

```
import chart_studio.plotly as py

import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = go.Figure(data=go.Heatmap(
               z=[code_lang['percentage']],
               x=code_lang['Language'],
               y=code_lang['Total Value'],
               hoverongaps = False))
fig.show()
```

It would be helpful if any better one is there

Comment: You first have to tell people what you want to visualize, what kind of graph, what kind of trend, what kind of heatmap, bar-chart, line chart, double y-axis chart... It's your data so you have to be clear on what you want to see in the figure

Comment: I wanted to see by language and percentage or total value  . Plotted with heatmap with color as language x axis as percentage and y as total value using matplotlib there was lot of overlaps hence deleted the code . Thought of bar graph ,displaying x axis with Languages ,this will be a chaos . I thought of bubble chart not sure of the syntax.  Basically the graph should be interpretable in such away that languages with higher percentage values should be highlighted and with lower percentage should also be viewed

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to show the data as a wordcloud.

Some remarks:

- the original Total_Value and Percentage columns are text strings; they need to be converted to numeric
- the Total_Value and Percentage columns have equivalent information: only one of the two needs to be shown
- a lot of the percentages are extremely small, so they get invisible with most types of visualization

```py
from wordcloud import WordCloud
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

# data=...
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.Percentage = df.Percentage.astype(float)
df.Total_Value = df.Total_Value.astype(int)

word_dict = {}
for row in df.itertuples(index=False):
    word_dict[row.Language] = row.Percentage

wordcloud = WordCloud(background_color="white", width=1200, height=1000
                      ).generate_from_frequencies(word_dict)
plt.axis('off')
plt.imshow(wordcloud)
plt.show()
```

In order to have the large values not overwhelm the smaller, the percentages could be brought closer together, e.g. using `word_dict[row.Language] = row.Percentage ** .2`.

[image: word cloud plot]